# I've lost my castle, how do I find where I built it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After generating a new creative world (large biomes) I went around looking for an extreme hills biome. I did this by `tp`ing randomly in x and z directions in multiples of 10,000 (or possibly 100,000).

My problem is, I died, and hadn't reset spawn. I've opened my map in Minutor, but couldn't find it easily. How on earth do I find the castle I just built?

Comment: How do you die in creative?

Comment: @John testing in survival...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I found it!**

[image]

MCEdit will tell you the dimensions of your world. I went to the extremities of mine, and found my castle!

Comment: Thank you fredley, but the princess is in another castle

Comment: Should post links or a how-to guide

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether the program you're using has this functionality, but you should filter your map for certain block types, such as glass or wood. This only spawns in a select few areas, so it will reduce the number of places you need look to find the castle again. If you have a block you only have in the castle, it will be easier to find your castle.

Comment: That's not the issue at all, it's that the viewport is too small to view things that sparsely spread out over such a large area.